# Undefined Variable in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

This is my function:

```
public function showDataall($result) 
    {
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($result) or die("failed!");
        $q->execute();
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

This function perfectly work in old xampp but new xampp return a Notice:

> Undefined variable: data in /opt/lampp/htdocs/live/demo/model/config.php on line 152

Comment: When you have 0 results it will show this error

Comment: define `$data=array();` before while loop

Comment: The code you show does not look like it is from `config.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes it does `return $data;`

Answer (score 3):

Declare variable before using it :

If your query returns no data, your current code will never actually create the $data array, and therefore when you try and return it, this error will happen.

```
public function showDataall($result) 
    {
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($result) or die("failed!");
        $q->execute();
        $data = array();
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```